# Solve the functional Equation:- $f(x+y)=3^xf(y)+9^yf(x)\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-equations

> **Problem Statement:-**
>
> Consider a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for which $f(1)=6$ and $$f(x+y)=3^x\cdot f(y)+9^y\cdot f(x),\;\;\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$$ then find $f(x)$.

**My attempt:-**

As the function is differentiable hence, we can differentiate the function w.r.t $x$ and $y$ but since $x$ and $y$ are independent, so $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, so we get

$$f'(x+y)=3^x\ln3\cdot f(y)+9^y\cdot f'(x)\tag{1}$$

From the functional equation given in the problem we have

$$f(0+0)=3^0\ln{3}\cdot f(0)+9^0\cdot f(0)\implies f(0)=0$$

$$\therefore (1)\implies f'(y)=\ln{3}f(y)+c\cdot 9^y\tag{where $c=f'(0)$}$$

I am pretty much stuck after this.

> If possible can you also tell me the line of thought that I should have while solving these types of problems.

Comment: Your last line is solving the equation is just a differential equation $y' = y + c9^t$, which can be solved with the standard methods.

Answer (score 6):

I just happened to come up with an answer that doesn't need any differentiation.

We are given 
$$f(x+y)=3^x\cdot f(y)+9^y\cdot f(x)$$

On interchanging $x$ and $y$, we get

$$f(y+x)=3^y\cdot f(x)+ 9^x\cdot f(y)$$

we get $$3^x\cdot f(y)+9^y\cdot f(x)=3^y\cdot f(x)+ 9^x\cdot f(y)\\
\implies f(y)\cdot (3^x-9^x)=f(x)\cdot (3^y-9^y)\\
\implies \dfrac{f(x)}{3^x-9^x}=\dfrac{f(y)}{3^y-9^y}=k(\text{say})$$

So, we get 
$$f(x)=k({3^x-9^x})$$
Since $f(1)=6$, so 
$$f(1)=k(-6)=6\implies k=-1$$

$$\therefore \boxed{f(x)=9^x-3^x}$$

I don't know whether there are some other functions that satisfy the given conditions, if there are then please do post that in your answer.

> And if you have some other approach please do post so that there is something new to learn.