# value of $\frac{g'(4)}{g'(2)}$ in functional equation

Tags: functions

> If $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $g(x+y)=2^xg(y)+4^yg(x),\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}.$ If $g(2)=3,$ Then $\displaystyle 14\frac{g'(4)}{g'(2)}=$

What I try:

$g(x+y)=2^xg(y)+4^yg(x)\cdots \cdots (1)$

Now partial derivative w r to $x,$ Treating $y$ as a constant.

$g'(x+y)(1+0)=2^x\ln(2)g(y)+4^yg'(x)\cdots (2)$

And differentiate w.r.to $y,$ Treating $x$ as a constant.

$\displaystyle g'(x+y)(0+1)=2^xg'(y)+4^y\ln(4)g(x)\cdots\cdots  (3)$

So from $(2)$ and $(3),$ we get

$\displaystyle 2^x\ln(2)g(y)+4^yg'(x)=2^xg'(y)+4^y\ln(4)g(x)$

$\displaystyle 2^x[\ln(2)g(y)-g'(y)]=4^y[\ln(4)g(x)-g'(x)]$

I did not understand How do I solve further,

Please have a look , Thanks

Comment: You are expected to find an expression for $g(x)$.  Find $g(1), then evaluate $g(x+1)=g(1+x)$ see what happens.  Usually in these problems it helps to find clever values to substitute in.

Comment: You do *not* need "to find an expression for $g(x)$". See my answer below.

Comment: A couple of similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187194/solve-the-functional-equation-fxy-3xfy9yfx-forall-x-y-in-mathbbr and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129600/let-fxy-2021xfy2021yfx-where-fx-is-continuous-and-f1-1-find

Comment: But in those "similar" questions, you are expected to solve completely the functional equation. The problem here is much simpler, it reduces to a Cramer system with 2 unknowns $g'(2)$ and $g'(4).$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389052/other-approach-to-find-fx-when-fxy-2xfy4yfx/4389069#4389069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: evaluate your equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ at $x=y=2.$